# Perpendicular Symbol as Matrix Superscript

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

If $A$ is a matrix that is not (necessarily) square, then what is $A^\perp$?

What I do know is:

- $A^\perp$ is a matrix, not the orthogonal complement
- It is related to the QR Decomposition.

And finally, is there a MATLAB command that will compute $A^\perp$?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's hard to guess what it is without the necessary context. Can you quote the relevant paragraph?

Comment: The theorem is about linear matrix inequalities: "If there exist invertible matrices $D_l$ and $D_r$ such that $D_l \Delta=\Delta D_r \forall \Delta$ and $(C^\perp)^*(M^*D_r^*D_rM-D_l^*D_l)C^\perp<0$, the system of equations $y-Mu$, $u=\Delta y$, $0=Cu$ has only the trivial solution.

Comment: Still need more context than that. Nothing to show me that this isn't just some step in solving a generalized Lyapunov equation or some such. Maybe it's the Schur decomposition?

Comment: The matrices $M$ and $\Delta$ describe a linear control system with a linear fractional transformation with input $u$ and output $y$. $C$ describes a set of linear constraints on the input. (We are trying to find whether or not the linear system meets a sufficient condition for robustness.)

The paper I'm looking at, if you can see it, is [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=480382&tag=1)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the [Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse). You can compute this in MATLAB with `pinv(A)`.

Comment: Given the context (see my comment above), it's not that.